# Wrong image being cached with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking, nsurlcache

I'm using `UIImageView+AFNetworking` to load images from a remote server on a table view. However, in some situations, the wrong images are cached (on `NSURLCache`, not only `AFImageCache`), i.e. the cache from a URL returns a response from another one (both used on the app).

My `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is pretty normal:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *dict = self.sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *placeholder = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"shield-flat"] tintedImageWithColor:[UIColor asbestosColor]];
    if (dict[@"first_url"] != [NSNull null]) {

        NSURLRequest *mandanteReq = [NSMutableURLRequest imageRequestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dict[@"first_url"]]];
        [cell.firstImageView setImageWithURLRequest:mandanteReq placeholderImage:placeholder success:NULL failure:NULL];
    } else {
        cell.firstImageView.image = placeholder;
    }


    if (dict[@"second_url"] != [NSNull null]) {
        NSURLRequest *visitanteReq = [NSMutableURLRequest imageRequestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dict[@"second_url"]]];
        [cell.secondImageView setImageWithURLRequest:visitanteReq placeholderImage:placeholder success:NULL failure:NULL];
    } else {
        cell.secondImageView.image = placeholder;
    }
    return cell;
```

}

Also, my category on `NSMutableURLRequest` that is used to create the request:

```
+ (NSMutableURLRequest *)imageRequestWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy;
    request.HTTPShouldHandleCookies = NO;
    request.HTTPShouldUsePipelining = YES;
    request.timeoutInterval = 10;
    [request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    return request;
}
```

I know that `dict` is the current object and that the URLs are fine too. I also trust that the server (Amazon S3) is sending the correct image.

The problem often occurs on the first install of the app (probably because the images are cached after).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you see if it still happens when you don't use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`?

Comment: The problem shouldn't be about it, because the problem is that `[NSURLCache sharedCache]` is storing the wrong response, not that the cell is being drawn wrong. I'll try it later today, though.

Comment: any luck with this problem?